# How do retrieve a URL protocol ("http" or "https")?

Tags: php

I am using the PHP lib Simple HTML Dom Parser, as suggested here ( [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php) ) to parse a webpage's html content.

To create the DOM, I have to do:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
```

The problem is that if I do:

```
$html = file_get_html('www.example.com');
```

without specifying the URL's protocol, I will get an error.

**My question is:**
How can I get to know if the URL with the protocol is "http://www.example.com/" or "https://www.example.com/" having in hands only the string "www.example.com"?

Comment: Well, you can't. Domain names are quite independent from the protocol used - might as well be `ftp://`, or something even more exotic. (as for the error: it's trying to open a local file named `www.example.com` - you probably don't have that on your disk :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out something smarter than assuming "http://" as default and, if it fails, try "https://"

```
if (!$html = file_get_html('http://' . $url)) $html = file_get_html('https://' . $url);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know because both could be valid. I would assume `http://` though because normal practice is to redirect http to https if it is required, and `file_get_html` should follow an HTTP 301 or 302 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use get_headers() on the http address and look for the Upgrade: request in the header.  If you get a valid response, use http.  Otherwise, try on https.